# PHP function inserts values in wrong place

Tags: php

The code below gets a list of all the .csv files in a directory. I have created the function **csvcolumnsum** to extract some information from each file (the sum of all values in column 3) and inject it within each list item.

The html output should look something like this:

```
<li>Filename (sum)</li>
```

But it comes out like this:

```
sum<li>Filename ()</li>
```

Can anyone point out why this is happening? Here is the relevant code.

```
require("csvcolumnsum.php");

echo "<ul class=\"users\">";
$handle=opendir("data");
while (($file = readdir($handle))!==false) {
    $file = preg_replace("/\\.[^.\\s]{3}$/","",$file);
    if (preg_match('/[^\.]/i', $file)) {
        $value = csvcolumnsum("data/".$file.".csv",3);
        echo "<li><a href=\"?form_name=$file\">$file(";
        echo $value;
        echo ")</a></li>";
    }
}
closedir($handle);
echo "</ul>";
```

**csvcolumnsum.php**

```
function csvcolumnsum($filename,$col) {
    $handle2 = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $data = fgetcsv($handle2);

    foreach ($data as $headercolumn) {}
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle2)) {
        $sum += $data[$col];
    }

    echo "<span>$sum</span>";

    fclose($handle2);
}
```

Comment: You should be looking up a tutorial on PHP or how languages work in general. Trying to "echo" something back to the parent function shows a deep misunderstanding of what's going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't how `echo` works. If your want your function to communicate a value back to the calling function, your function needs to `return` the value, not `echo` it:

```
return "<span>$sum</span>";
```

Echo writes directly to the standard output, meaning this line:

```
$value = csvcolumnsum("data/".$file.".csv",3);
```

prints before these lines:

```
echo "<li><a href=\"?form_name=$file\">$file(";
echo $value;
echo ")</a></li>";
```

Returning halts execution in the current function, meaning your `close` will need to occur before your `return`:

```
function csvcolumnsum($filename,$col) {
    $handle2 = fopen($filename, 'r');

    # ...

    fclose($handle2);

    return "<span>$sum</span>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're `echo`ing not `return`ing in the `csvcolumnsum` function.

Answer (score 1):

you echo the sum you have to return it,

```
function csvcolumnsum($filename,$col) {
    $handle2 = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $data = fgetcsv($handle2);

    foreach ($data as $headercolumn) {}
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle2)) {
        $sum += $data[$col];
    }

    return "<span>$sum</span>";

    fclose($handle2);
}
```